# Copy an ipaddress into the UIP_ICMP_PAYLOAD

Tags: c, contiki

I am trying to improve the RPL protocol, and have therefore implemented a new control-message. I am able to send integers, but not ip-addresses. Can anyone help med? I am working in the file `rpl-icmp6.c` located at `contiki/core/net/rpl`.

This is my first function, which is receiving the data:

```
static void
tru_input(void)
{   
   int trustValue;
   uip_ipaddr_t *trustAddr;
   unsigned char *buffer;
   buffer = UIP_ICMP_PAYLOAD;

   trustValue = buffer[0];
   memcpy(&trustAddr, buffer[1], 16);

   PRINT6ADDR(trustAddr);

}
```

And this is the function that is sending the data:

```
void
tru_output(uip_ipaddr_t *addr, uip_ipaddr_t *trustAddr, int *trustValue)
{
  unsigned char *buffer;
  buffer = UIP_ICMP_PAYLOAD;
  buffer[0] = &trustValue;
  memcpy(buffer[1], &trustAddr, 16);
  uip_icmp6_send(addr, ICMP6_RPL, RPL_CODE_TRU, 1);
}
```

I receive an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1. Can anybody help me?

EDIT:

This is my new code which works:

```
static void
tru_input(void)
{   
  int trustValue;
  uip_ipaddr_t trustAddr;
  unsigned char *buffer;

  buffer = UIP_ICMP_PAYLOAD;

  trustValue = buffer[0];
  memcpy(&trustAddr, buffer + 1, 16);

  PRINT6ADDR(trustAddr);
  PRINTF("\n");

 }
 /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void
tru_output(uip_ipaddr_t *addr, uip_ipaddr_t *trustAddr, int trustValue)
{
  /*Array OF byte: Find out how to enter all the bytes into the PAYLOAD. */
  unsigned char *buffer;
  buffer = UIP_ICMP_PAYLOAD;
  buffer[0] = trustValue;

  memcpy(buffer + 1, trustAddr, 16);
  uip_icmp6_send(addr, ICMP6_RPL, RPL_CODE_TRU, 17);
 }
```

Comment: It looks like the issue was with basic C semantics, not with Contiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
memcpy(&trustAddr, buffer[1], 16);
```

You are coping the value pointing to buffer[1] (that is a char) to the value that is pointing trustAddr
i think you would like to pass the address of buffer[1]:

```
memcpy(&trustAddr, buffer + 1, 16);
```

The same in tru_output (you don't need to pass the ponter of trustAddr to memcpy, because you already declared it as a pointer:

```
memcpy(buffer+1, trustAddr, 16);
```

I see that you also need to inizialize trustAddr with 16 byte, becouse you are coping memory to a random memory region, so don't declare trustAddr as a pointer:

```
uip_ipaddr_t trustAddr;
```

Comment: If I want to print the correct ip address after receiving it in tru_input, should   i print it like this: `PRINT6ADDR(&trustAddr)` or like this: `PRINT6ADDR(trustAddr)`?

Comment: PRINT6ADDR(trustAddr), becouse trustAddr in tru_input is already an address

Comment: I receive this error tho: `expected 'const union uip_ip_addr_t *' but was 'uip_ipaddr_t'`. If I use the code that I edited into my question. However, if I use `PRINT6ADDR(&trustAddr)`, I get an IP-address but not the correct one. Do you know what is wrong? :)

Comment: sorry I've watched the wrong function. can you paste the expecting ip and the ip that you obtaing? I think might be because of the network byte order

Comment: Ofcourse! expected IP: `fe80::c30c:0:0:6` received IP: `f001:10:f200:aa:aa00::`

Comment: nope, doesn't seem to be that kind of problem. i think the problem in another piece of code. Only check if UIP_ICMP_PAYLOAD effectly contains the expected ip. if yes, it may be the offset that you are using in the memcpy

Comment: In tru_output, first I set the buffer to be `memcpy(buffer, trustAddr, 16);`. After this, before I send the packets, i try to copy the address to a new variable: `memcpy(&trustAddr2, buffer, 16);` and print it. `trustAddr2` now have the correct address, so I think it is something with the network.

Comment: Thanks so much! The error was that when I send the icmp message, I specify that only one byte was going to be sent. If I set this to be 17, it works!! :)